# Make AutoCompletionTextView show suggestions not complement of text

Tags: android

i want to make a AutoCompletionTextView show suggestions

the behavior is to look in the data which is the ArrayAdapter and make suggestions

suggestions list will be a list of all texts that have the same sequence of characters

like i type abc and the data list have [ abc , fabc, geabcr, fgkd, abcg, meow]
and the suggestions will be [abc, fabc, geabcr ,abcg](see all suggestions have abc in them)

Comment: you need to provide your custom `android.widget.Filter` then or use `SimpleCursorAdapter` with a custom `FilterQueryProvider`

Comment: I'm a beginner so can u plz tell how to do it?

Comment: if you are beginner then start from SimpleCursorAdapter and a custom FilterQueryProvider